# Need help to save HDD

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I recently checked my second HDD and saw that its one attribute is about to fail. how can I refresh or fix it? 
is there any program or way to fix?
Please
[image: Smart data]

Comment: As you can learn in the linked question, your disk is about to physically die. This can't be repaired, you should back up your data as soon as possible and replace the disk.

Comment: I can't use it anymore, can I?

Comment: You can use it until it completely dies, of course, if you can bear the high risk of data corruption or loss at any time. I strongly discourage that, though.

Comment: You _can_ keep using it, but you probably will loose your data - do a backup _now_ !